# DateTimeKind.Utc vs DateTimeKind.Local

Tags: c#

Both of these produce the same result but I expected them to be off by 6 hours. What am I not understanding?

```
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 12, 1, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToString("R"));
\\ Thu, 01 Jan 1970 12:01:00 GMT

Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 12, 1, 0, DateTimeKind.Local).ToString("R"));
\\ Thu, 01 Jan 1970 12:01:00 GMT
```

Comment: Ah, but try `(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 12, 1, 0, DateTimeKind.Local)).ToUniversalTime().ToString("R")`

Comment: @john stuff like that is why NodaTime is a thing :) It's just more explicit in doing things.

Comment: If you use `O` as the formatter, then the "right" timezone is shown for second one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ToString` prints the `DateTime` as is. You have to convert them both to the same kind to be able to see the difference: add `.ToUniversalTime()`:

```
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 12, 1, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToUniversalTime().ToString("R"));
// Thu, 01 Jan 1970 12:01:00 GMT

Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 12, 1, 0, DateTimeKind.Local).ToUniversalTime().ToString("R"));
// Thu, 01 Jan 1970 11:01:00 GMT <-- I am at GMT+1
```

Comment: Only exception seems to be `O`, that is round-trip format. It works in an intelligent way.

Answer (score 1):

It's related to the format you're using.

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-rfc1123-r-r-format-specifier):

> *The "R" or "r" standard format specifier represents a custom date and time format string that is defined by the DateTimeFormatInfo.RFC1123Pattern property. The pattern reflects a defined standard, and the property is read-only. Therefore, it is always the same, regardless of the culture used or the format provider supplied. The custom format string is "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'". When this standard format specifier is used, the formatting or parsing operation always uses the invariant culture.*

EDIT : "R" or "r" format do not say that the time shown is UTC time. It just say that they use the format "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'". The GMT string is a bit confusing but it's just a string without meaning here ...

Comment: *It's related to the format you're using.* Not really. If you use a culture-dependent format, like `g`, you still see the same times.

Comment: Who said "g" format was showing UTC time ? Neither do "R" or "r" format.
The 'GMT' string is a bit confusing.

Comment: Okay. Then that was unclear from your answer. You might want to clarify that.